# java mongodb "geoNear" command return exception error 17304

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial, geo

I am using mongoDB to store and fetch location-related information in a java application.

I got an exception while using "geoNear" to fetch data...

this is the code of storing data:

```
Document doc = new Document(Params.pubId, UUID.fromString(tmsg.pubId))
                                            .append(Params.location, new Point(new Position(tloc.lat, tloc.lon)))
                                            .append(Params.locId, UUID.fromString(tloc.id))
                                            .append(Params.pubTime, tmsg.pubTime)
                                            .append(Params.span, tmsg.span)
                                            .append(Params.messageId, UUID.fromString(tmsg.id))
                                            .append(Params.header, tmsg.header)
                                            .append(Params.senderId, UUID.fromString(tmsg.senderId))
                                            .append(Params.senderDisp, tmsg.name)   
                                            .append(Params.homes, homes)
                                            .append(Params.tags, tags);

collection.insertOne(doc);
```

and this is the code of fetching

```
Document command = new Document("geoNear",Params.collection).append("near", new Point(new Position(loc.lat, loc.lon)))
                                                                          .append("spherical", true)
                                                                          .append("limit", Params.limit)
                                                                          .append("maxDistance", plan.range)
                                                                          .append("distanceMultiplier", Params.multplierKm);
                //the "geoNear" will always return a non-null object
                Document geoNear = database.runCommand(command);
```

and the exception print out

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17304: ''near' field must be point' on server data.gubnoi.com:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "'near' field must be point", "code" : 17304, "codeName" : "Location17304" }
```

it is a bit weird that the occurrence of this exception is dependent.

in the success case, I used mocked coordinates of 0.0, 0.0; and I did store some data on this coordinates beforehand. as I said the operation was success, and I can fetch the stored data successfully.

in the failed case, I feed in real coordinates acquired by a mobile terminal such as

```
lat:39.904522 lon: 116.65588
```

also, no data had been stored on that location beforehand. and then the follwing statement failed with the exception

```
Document geoNear = database.runCommand(command);
```

I am using mongo-java-driver 3.4.1 under Java 8, and mongodb 3.4.1

please advise

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used mocked coordinates of 0.0, 0.0; and I did store some data on this coordinates beforehand. as I said the operation was success.

Try reversing the order of the coordinates value; MongoDB coordinates order is `longitude` then `latitude`. For example:

```
new Point(new Position(loc.lon, loc.lat))
```

It works for `0.0`, `0.0` because both value are valid on reverse (i.e. unidentifiable as lat or long).

You can also reproduce this error using [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/):

```
> db.runCommand({geoNear: "places",
                 near: { type: "Point", 
                         coordinates: [ 39.904522, 116.65588 ] 
                       },
                 spherical: true    
});

{
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "'near' field must be point",
  "code": 17304,
  "codeName": "Location17304"
}
```